# SQL statement selects top 10 orders from each country in a list of countries

Tags: sql, teradata

I'm trying to build a query where I can get the top 10 orders from each country in a list of countries. So that if my list of countries is 3 long, I should get no more than 30 result total and no more than 10 from one country.

Assume the table I am querying has the necessary fields.

My list of countries can change with the query. So at one point I may just be interested in ('China', 'Japan', 'USA') but at another ('China', 'Japan', 'Germany') for example.

Answer (score 1):

In Teradata, you would use the `qualify` clause:

```
select o.*
from orders o
qualify row_number() over (partition by country order by total desc) <= 10;
```

Comment: My list of countries can change with the query. So at one point I may just be interested in ('China', 'Japan', 'USA') but at another ('China', 'Japan', 'Germany') for example.

Comment: You would just include a constraint - `where country in ('A','B','C',...)`.  The qualify will give you the top 10 for each country in your output.  That's what the partition clause does

Comment: @ChristopherJordanBigelow . . . You would add a `where` clause for the countries you are interested in.